# The word ending "-ita/-ito" and its usage

Tags: diferencias-regionales, diminutivos

**English:**

From what I've seen, the *-ita/-ito* ending is used for describing little things, or as a better way of describing time periods, especially in businesses (like a waitress saying *La comida va a estar lista en 15 minutitos.*) Here a some others I've personally heard:

> libro > librito (a small book)
>
> niña > niñita (a small girl)
>
> ahora > ahorita (right now)
>
> tiempo > tiempito (in a little time)

My question: is this one of those blanket endings that can be applied to pretty much any noun with the effect of describing it as smaller? Or is it a regional dialect/slang? How do I properly apply this ending?

I've also heard this:

> chiquititita (very, very, very small)

**Español:**

Por lo que he visto, la *-ita/-ito* final se utiliza para describir las cosas pequeñas, o como una mejor forma de describir periodos de tiempo, especialmente en las empresas (como una camarera diciendo *La comida va a estar lista es 15 minutitos*) Aquí hay algunos otros que he escuchado personalmente:

> libro > librito (a small book)
>
> niña > niñita (a small girl)
>
> ahora > ahorita (right now)
>
> tiempo > tiempito (in a little time)

Mi pregunta: ¿es este un sufijo universal que se puede aplicar a casi cualquier sustantivo con el efecto de describirlo como más pequeño? ¿O es un dialecto / argot regional? ¿Cómo puedo aplicar correctamente este sufijo?

También he oído esto:

> chiquititita (very, very, very small)

Comment: as a side note: you can also find chirriquitica which is a cubanism, notice how the suffix is not in the end of the noun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### English

The *-ito* ending, like most diminuitives, is productive.  As *syrux* points out, other ones like *-uco*, *-eto*, *-ico*, *-illo*, *-ino*, and *-ín* are used more commonly in certain areas and tend to be equally as productive (to his list can also be added *-iño* from Galicia and *-ingo* from the Andes).  When we say a suffix is productive, that means that, theoretically, it can be added to any word and the meaning would be more or less transparently understood by a native speaker.

That said, in the *Gramática 9.2g* (pp. 634-5), the RAE notes that

> Some words reject appreciative suffixes.  The reasons can be categorical, phonetic (§ 9.5ñ, v), and also semantic.  Relational adjectives, which are studied in § 13.12, tend not to allow them (*aéreo, musical, presidencial, pulmonar*).  As seen in § 9.2c, ordinal adjectives can join this group.  Normally, many nouns that denote characteristics, qualities, and physical or animate state (*alegría, altura, bondad, equilibrio*, yet *dudita, muertecita, pasioncilla* do exist), among other abstract notions, reject the diminuitives.

Notice how there is some wiggle room in the rejection.  Just because it won't normally be done, doesn't mean it would necessarily be misunderstood if heard.  Where you do need to be careful is working with the great variety of infixes (like *-c-* and *-ec-* for *-ito*) that may need to be applied.  If you read through the *Gramática*, you'll see the rules are hardly fixed (most people maintain stem-changing vowels, some revert them as necessary, for instance) and so two educated speakers may very well give you opposing views as to whether a given word can take a diminuitive, and if so, how you ought to form it.

### Spanish

El sufijo *-ito*, como la mayoría de los diminuitivos, es productivo hoy en día.  Como apunta *syrux*, según la zona, uno u otro diminuitivo como *-uco*, *-eto*, *-ico*, *-illo*, *-ino*, and *-ín* tendrá más o menos popularidad (podemos también reconocer *-iño*, de Galicia, e *-ingo* del español andino).  Al decir que un sufijo es productivo, quiérese decir que, teorícamente, se lo puedes añadir a cualquier palabra y el significado del resultado será entendido más o menos transparentemente por un hablante nativo.

No obstante, en la *Gramática 9.2g* (pp. 634-5), la RAE reconoce que

> Algunas palabras rechazan los sufijos apreciativos.  Las razones pueden ser categoriales, fonéticas (§ 9.5ñ, v) y también semánticas.  No los suelen admitir los adjetivos de relación (*aéreo, musical, presidencial, pulmonar*), que se examina en el § 13.12.  Como se vio en el § 9.2c, los adjetivos ordinales puede asimilarse a este grupo. Normalmente rechazan los diminuitivos muchos sustantivos que denotan características, cualidades y estados físicos o anímicos (*alegría, altura, bondad, equilibrio*, pero existen *dudita, muertecita, pasioncilla*), entre otras nociones abstractas.

Fíjate como el rechazo no es total.  El hecho de que normalmente no se adjuntará un sufijo a una palabra no significa que tal palabra sufijada será malentendida.   El cuidado que debes tener es por la gran variedad de infijos (como *-c-* y *-ec-* en el caso de *-ito*).  Si lees la *Gramática*, verás que las reglas no son nada fijas (p.ej. la mayoría de las personas conservan el diptongo en palabras con alternancia vocálica, pero alguna gente restaura el monoptongo al añadir el sufijo); por eso puede que dos hablantes cultos te den respuestas contrarias de que si una palabra admite un diminuitivo y, en su caso, cómo se la debe formar.

Answer (score 3):

To expound a bit on the other answers, and address one specific part of the question:

> Or is it a regional dialect/slang?

The grammatical use of *-ita* / *-ito* is universal, however the idiomatic use of certain words is anything but!

As an example mentioned in your question, "ahorita" is the normal way, in Mexico, to say "Right now" or "In just a moment" (or some times even "never"... depending on context).  But in Spain this word sounds strange where "Ahora mismo" is the understood way to say "right now' or "in just a moment."

> Yo: Me traes un café, ¿por favor?
>   Mesera: Ahorita. **(México)**
>   Mesera: Ahora mismo. **(España)**

Comment: Por lo general en mexico y centroamerica es entendido como right now, pero fuera de ahi es entendido como en un rato, recuerdos mis malos entendidos en las cafeterias mexicanas que me decian ahorita y yo le decia que no, que ahora mismo por favor. Lol

Comment: @EmilioGort: "Vamos, estamos tarde!" "Sí! Ahorita voy... solo tengo que poner mi maquillaje." <--- Un contexto común en que quiere decir "in just a moment."  Y otro ejemplo: "¿Qué me dijiste?" "Ahorita te digo." <-- Un ejemplo en que quiere decir "Never" (pero claro es un ejemplo de ironía).

Comment: si yo se, era para recalcar las diferencias regionales, casi todos los años voy a playa del carmen y me cuesta sincronizar con ellos eso del ahorita, imaginate con 5 cervezas en un bar y poniendome a pensar a esa hora...lol

Comment: I agreed with your initial answer, but not after the edition. It is not true that adverbs cannot take diminutives. Some of them can (*cerquita*, *prontito*), some of them cannot (*sí*, *más*, any adverb ending in *-mente*).

Comment: @Gorpik: A fair observation. I was challenged by another user on that point... but your point is more compelling. I have rolled back to my original version.

Comment: @Flimzy OK, I've upvoted you back. By the way, even though it is not used in Spain, I think everybody here would understand *ahorita* or *ahorita mismo*, also pinpointing the likely Mexican or Central American origin of the speaker. And we wouldn't say *mesera* in Spain, we'd say *camarera* ;)

Comment: @Gorpik: Ah right... they say "camarera" in Mexico, too, but it refers primarily to a hotel maid :)

Comment: @Flimzy No wonder, since the word *camarera* comes from *cámara* (chamber). So, initially, it meant chamber-maid, but later the meaning was generalised and nowadays it is also used for waitresses and bartenders.

Answer (score 2):

### No

En Español los sufijos diminutivos marcan generalmente tamaño pequeño, juventud, cariño o desdén, pero no hay un estudio definitivo y las pautas obedecen en gran medida a los usos locales o particulares del hablante.

Sobre el uso de *ahorita*: uno de los casos más comunes es *"ahorita"*; que usado especialmente en México para indicar urgencia, es usado internacionalmente para describir posteridad, falta de prisa.

Otros ejemplos:

- -uc- es un sufijo asturiano y cántabro.
- -et- corriente en la parte oriental de España.
- -ic- se usa mucho en Aragón, Navarra, País Valenciano castellanoparlante, Andalucía oriental, Albacete y Murcia.
- -ill- especialmente común en Andalucía, y otros son -it-, el más usado; -ino, propio de Extremadura.
- -ín, propio de León y Asturias.

Comment: *Ahora* no es un sustantivo, sino un adverbio (la pregunta habla de sustantivos, aunque mencione ese ejemplo erróneamente). No recuerdo ningún sustantivo al que no se pueda aplicar el diminutivo, y la forma *-ito, -ita* es la más internacional (comprensible y utilizable en cualquier zona hispanohablante, aunque coexista con alguna variedad regional).

Comment: @Gorpik, los diminutivos pueden usarse en en los adverbios, (tempranito) incluso en gerundios (caminandito). Aparte de eso nunca entendí lo que significaba "¿es este uno de esos finales de manta que se pueden aplicar a casi cualquier sustantivo con el efecto de describirlo como más pequeño?"

Comment: @syrux es una mala traducción por calco directo de la palabra anglófona *blanket* (manta) que como adjetivo significa universal, sin excepción, o *que cubre todo* (de ahí su origen).  Quería saber si siempre puede significar pequeño, cosa que es más o menos verdad, excepto por influencia de significados opacos (cuando han sido lexicalizados y tienen significados ajenos o difíciles de discifrar de la palabra base)

Comment: @guifa, por eso me molesto cuando traducen mal al Inglés. Imagina la complejidad de tu comentario traducida al Inglés.

Comment: @syrux Desde luego, los diminutivos pueden usarse en algunos adverbios. Pero si la pregunta incluyera los adverbios, la respuesta sería diferente: no todos los adverbios los admiten. Por ejemplo, los terminados en *-mente* no pueden tomar diminutivos. Y lo mismo ocurre con muchos de los más usados, como *sí*, *no*, *más*, *menos*... Incluso tenemos casos que parecen contradictorios: *poco* admite el diminutivo, pero *mucho* no. Por eso me ha parecido más correcto señalar que el ejemplo *ahora* es incorrecto que modificar la pregunta original, que habla de sustantivos.

Comment: @Gorpik, yo sinceramente no entendí del todo la pregunta, estaba tan mal traducida.

Comment: @syrux Ya lo creo :) Yo he ignorado la traducción al castellano y he ido directamente a la versión inglesa.

Answer (score 0):

> is this one of those blanket endings that can be applied to pretty much any noun with the effect of describing it as smaller?

It is usable on all nouns as far as I know. Spanish is pretty straightforward and consistent, apart from any Arabic influences.  I can't think of any nouns you couldn't use it on.

There is also *-illo/illa.*  They are pretty much interchangeable and anyone's preference on which one to use depends on what they grew up saying; it's a matter of dialect.